# I am trying to deploy a nextJS blog integrated with graphCMS to vercel but i am getting a couple of errors

Tags: next.js, graphcms

After clicking on the framework preset and deploying to vercel, I get this error:

No Next.js version could be detected in your project. Make sure `"next"` is installed in "dependencies" or "devDependencies"

even though I have next in my dependencies as shown below:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "graphql": "^16.6.0",
        "graphql-request": "^5.0.0",
        "html-react-parser": "^3.0.4",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "next": "^12.3.1",
        "nextjs": "^0.0.3",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.2",
        "sass": "^1.54.9"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "17.0.35",
        "@types/react": "18.0.9",
        "@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
        "postcss": "^8.4.14",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.2",
        "typescript": "4.7.2"
    }
}
```

How do I get to fix this error and have a successful deployment, cause when I change the preset to  "other" it deploys but gives a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. I manually installed next.js

- npm install next react react-dom

https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started

and it deployed to Vercel successfully.

Comment: Added all that, still didn't work